# Linear transformation satisfies $T^n=T$; has eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ over a (finite, is needed) field $F$, which satisfies $T^n=T$.
Prove that $T$ has a eigenvalue, or give a counter example.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, welcome to SE. What are your thoughts on the problem? You should review the guidelines for posting questions.

Comment: It is a part of some bigger issue I'm having with my non-commutative algebra homework. V does not have to be finite dimensional. tried for some hours, don't have a promising direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. The matrix $$A = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$ satisfies $A^4 = 1$ (thus $A^5 = A$) but its characteristic polynomial $X^2+1$ has no real roots, so $A$ has no real eigenvalues.

For an example over a finite field, consider 
$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$
over $\mathbb F_2$. It satisfies $A^3 = 1$ (thus $A^4 = A$) but the characteristic polynomial $X^2+X+1$ has no root in $\mathbb F_2$.